# svcutil only generates client code for one of multiple service contracts

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I have a service with multiple service contracts, when I run svcutil.exe, it only generates client code for one contract or the other (it seems to switch every time I run it).  Some more info:
service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class BackendService : IBackendService, IFitContract
{
     //implementation
}
```

My web.config looks like:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding/>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

svcutil call:

```
svcutil.exe /config:App.config /out:BackendService.cs /n:*,BackendServer /r:bin/Debug/CSCommon.dll http://localhost:56725/BackendService.svc?wsdl
```

any thoughts to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't declare any endpoints for the service on web.config, WCF will add one default endpoint to it. Since you have two options for this endpoint, WCF will simply choose 1 (I don't know what it does to choose it). So in this case you need to declare the endpoints explicitly, as shown below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="BackendServiceNamespace.BackendService">
      <endpoint address="ibs"
                contract="BackendServiceNamespace.IBackendService"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" />
      <endpoint address="ifc"
                contract="BackendServiceNamespace.IFitContract"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I thought the purpose of the protocol mapping was so we don't need to manually add endpoints (in 4.0)